# Term for a page which establishes Reputation, or "Why Choose Us"

Tags: terminology

I have created a page on a website for a high end catering company. So far, I titled the page "Clients", but this doesn't really fit the bill anymore.

On this page, I do have a list of clients: logos of well known companies that the company has done work for. I also include testimonials from their clients, as well as press links (blogs, etc) praising or showcasing their services.

Something like a "Why Choose Us" doesn't feel appropriate for a high end service industry page. I also like "Praise", but that doesn't necessarily fit the list of clients that I have. What is a good term for the title of this page?

Comment: How about 'quality service'? It's the quality that you're trying to promote.

Answer (score 2):

You described a page that is usually on the websites with the name "About us" or just "About". I like "About" because related with a good content that implies the users seems a short version of "About us and you".

On the other hand, "Customers" or "Clients" establish the fact your product has already success. I saw this approach on the [Invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/customers) website where the page is "Customers" and the title "WHY DO SO MANY OF THE WORLD'S SMARTEST COMPANIES USE INVISION?".

I think you should choose what is the best for your product and what is more important that the users know first.

Comment: I agree with Madalina's approach. The use of a general term on the link help people navigate the website since it's a term that people are used to see, like About. And inside the page, you have a title or subtitle, with more marketing jargon, explaining the content of the page, like:
> Which company we served
> What the media said about us
> What our clients said about us

Answer (score 0):

Who do you want to view the page?

Usually displaying logos of established brands is a method to show potential customers that your products are good. "If xxx is using it, it must be good." From that perspective, on which page would potential customers look for this info? 'Clients' is a very good indicator, so even though there is a lot more content you at least get the right people on the right page.

Alternatively, could you split the content into multiple pages that feel more coherent? Maybe 'clients' and 'press'?

Comment: I did think about splitting the pages, but the problem is that there are only three "Press" articles, so it doesn't really warrant an entire page and menu link to it. You make a good point that Clients is a gets the point across, and will attract visitors.

Answer (score 0):

One of the patterns I have often seen is a header of "About Us" with anchors to "Clients", "Press" and "Blogs".

So the main navigation would look like,

- Products

  - Product A
  - Product B
- Pricing
- Customer Service
- About Us

  - Clients
  - Press
  - Blogs

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to a portfolio or section of a standard digital website. But in this case being a catering company, something like "Who We've Served".